# How to publish Spring Kafka DLQ in 2.5.4 version

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

need your help and guidance on this.

I was using 2.2.X version spring-kafka in my current project.

The error handling that I created looks like this:

```
@Bean("kafkaConsumer")
public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Map<String, Object>> eventKafkaConsumer() {
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Map<String, Object>> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    factory.setErrorHandler(new SeekToCurrentErrorHandler(createDeadLetterPublishingRecoverer(), 3));
    return factory;
}

public DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer createDeadLetterPublishingRecoverer() {
    return new DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer(getEventKafkaTemplate(),
            (record, ex) -> new TopicPartition("topic-undelivered", -1));
}
```

And then I upgraded all my project dependency version, such as spring-boot and the spring-kafka into the latest one : **2.5.4 RELEASE**

I found that some of the methods were deprecated and changed.

[SeekToCurrentErrorHandler](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#seek-to-current)

```
SeekToCurrentErrorHandler errorHandler =
new SeekToCurrentErrorHandler((record, exception) -> {
    // recover after 3 failures, woth no back off - e.g. send to a dead-letter topic
}, new FixedBackOff(0L, 2L));
```

My question is,
how to produce the DLQ with these configurations:

**EDITED**

```
@Bean("kafkaConsumer")
public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Map<String, Object>> kafkaConsumer() {
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Map<String, Object>> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
    factory.setConcurrency(consumerConcurrencyCount);
    factory.setErrorHandler(errorHandler());
    return factory;
}

public SeekToCurrentErrorHandler errorHandler() {
    return new SeekToCurrentErrorHandler(
            deadLetterPublishingRecoverer(),
            new FixedBackOff(0L, 2L)
    );
}

public DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer deadLetterPublishingRecoverer() {
    return new DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer(
            getEventKafkaTemplate(),
            (record, ex) -> {
                if (ex.getCause() instanceof BusinessException || ex.getCause() instanceof TechnicalException) {
                    return new TopicPartition("topic-undelivered", -1);
                }

                return new TopicPartition("topic-fail", -1);
            });
}

public KafkaOperations<String, Object> getEventKafkaTemplate() { // producer to DLQ
    return new KafkaTemplate<>(new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(producerConfigs()));
}
```

This configurations work, thanks to Gary!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear what you mean by

> The problem is, in the documentation, it's still using the old method, which is deprecated for 2.5.X version

The `KafkaOperations` is an interface that the `KafkaTemplate` implements; the only change you need to make is to change the `maxAttempts` to a `BackOff`...

```java
@Bean("kafkaConsumer")
public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Map<String, Object>> eventKafkaConsumer() {
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Map<String, Object>> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    factory.setErrorHandler(new SeekToCurrentErrorHandler(createDeadLetterPublishingRecoverer(), new FixedBackOff(0, 2L));
    return factory;
}

public DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer createDeadLetterPublishingRecoverer() {
    return new DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer(getEventKafkaTemplate(),
            (record, ex) -> new TopicPartition("topic-undelivered", -1));
}
```

Comment: Hi Gary, thanks for the answer. I did change only on the BackOff, but the KafkaOperation is wrong.   
public KafkaTemplate<Object, Object> getKafkaTemplate() {
        return new KafkaTemplate<>(new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(producerConfigs()));
    }

and the producerConfigs() is a Map<String, Object> type.

When I tried getKafkaTemplate.send("topic", "msg"), there was an error.

Comment: It doesn't matter; either you can ignore the deprecation warning or change your method to `KafkaOperations<Object, Object> getKafkaTemplate() `. `there was an error` - what error? If it's more than the deprecation warning, edit the question to show your complete code and the error; don't try to put such things in a comment, as you can see it's hard to read.

Comment: Hi Gary, yes sure! I have edited the question. Sorry for the inconvenient since I'm new on using this platform. Can u please check on the edited version and help with the solution. Thanks

Comment: This is wrong: `new SeekToCurrentErrorHandler((record, exception) -> createDeadLetterPublishingRecoverer(), ...`; it should be `new SeekToCurrentErrorHandler(createDeadLetterPublishingRecoverer(), ...` and this is wrong `new DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer(
            getEventKafkaTemplate().send("topic", null), ...` it should be `new DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer(getEventKafkaTemplate(), ...`. Also change the return type of `getEventKafkaTemplate()` to `KafkaOperations` to get rid of the deprecation warning. Did you even read my answer?

Comment: Yes Gary, I was testing it to create dlq on specific exceptions. Btw, all works now, all I need was to change to FixedBackOff n the KafkaOperations. Thank you so much @Gary

Comment: Is there a way to use RetryPolicy from factory and setErrorHandler the same way he uses it ?

Comment: Retry at the listener level is deprecated, now that the error handlers have much more sophistication. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/1886